RelayCommand inheritance in ViewModel
I'm designing a master/detail view-model scheme, so I created a base class that implements Add, Edit, Save, Cancel and Delete commands and also manages the CanExecute logic for these commands. However, the Save and Delete commands need to be partially implemented in the derived class, but they must still be present in the base class to manage the CanExecute logic.
In short, I tried the RelayCommand inheritance this way:
// Base class
   protected IRelayCommand SaveCommand { get; }
   protected void Save()
   {
      // [...]
   }

   protected IRelayCommand DeleteCommand { get; }
   protected void Delete()
   {
      // [...]
   }

// Derived class
   [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSave))]
   private void Save()
   {
      // [...]
      base.Save();
   }

   [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanDelete))]
   private void Delete()
   {
      // [...]
      base.Delete();
   }

In more detail, the base class:
internal abstract partial class MasterDetailViewModelBase<TDetailViewModel> : ObservableObject
{
   // [...]

   private TDetailViewModel? currentItem;
   public TDetailViewModel? CurrentItem
   {
      get => currentItem;
      set
      {
         if (EqualityComparer<TDetailViewModel?>.Default.Equals(currentItem, value)) return;
         SetProperty(ref currentItem, value);
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasCurrentItem));
         NotifyButtonsState();
      }
   }

   public bool HasCurrentItem => CurrentItem is not null;

   private void NotifyButtonsState()
   {
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanAdd));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanEdit));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanSave));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanCancel));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanDelete));
      AddCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();      // [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(AddCommand))]
      EditCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();     // [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(EditCommand))]
      SaveCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();     // [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SaveCommand))]
      CancelCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();   // [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(CancelCommand))]
      DeleteCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();   // [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(DeleteCommand))]
   }

   public bool CanAdd => HasCurrentItem ? CurrentItem.State == ItemState.Unchanged : true;
   public bool CanEdit => HasCurrentItem ? CurrentItem.State == ItemState.Unchanged : false;
   public bool CanSave => HasCurrentItem ? CurrentItem.IsChanged : false;
   public bool CanCancel => HasCurrentItem
                                 ? CurrentItem.State == ItemState.Adding ||
                                   CurrentItem.State == ItemState.Editing
                                 : false;
   public bool CanDelete => HasCurrentItem ? CurrentItem.State == ItemState.Unchanged : false;

   [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanAdd))]
   private void Add()
   {
      // [...]
   }

   [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanEdit))]
   private void Edit()
   {
      // [...]
   }

   //
   // That's how CommunityToolkit.Mvvm implements the RelayCommand attribute:
   //
   //private RelayCommand? saveCommand;
   //public IRelayCommand SaveCommand => saveCommand ??= new RelayCommand(new Action(Save), () => CanSave);
   //
   protected IRelayCommand SaveCommand { get; }
   protected void Save()
   {
      // [...]
   }

   [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanCancel))]
   private void Cancel()
   {
      // [...]
   }

   protected IRelayCommand DeleteCommand { get; }
   protected void Delete()
   {
      // [...]
   }
}

And the derived class:
internal partial class CustomersViewModel : MasterDetailViewModelBase<CustomerViewModel>
{
   [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSave))]
   private void Save()
   {
      // [...]

      base.Save();
   }

   [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanDelete))]
   private void Delete()
   {
      // [...]

      base.Delete();
   }
}

But doing it this way causes an error in the function that notifies the status of the buttons, NotifyButtonsState():
   private void NotifyButtonsState()
   {
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanAdd));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanEdit));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanSave));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanCancel));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanDelete));
      AddCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
      EditCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
      SaveCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();     // <-- ERROR
      CancelCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
      DeleteCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
   }

The error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'


I came to the conclusion that I can't do this using the RelayCommandAttribute, from the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm package, I have to write the code myself.
As I want to leave as little work as possible to the derived class, I came up with this solution:
Base class:
   private RelayCommand? saveCommand;
   protected IRelayCommand SaveCommand => saveCommand;
   protected IRelayCommand GetSaveCommand(Action execute)
   {
      return saveCommand ??= new RelayCommand(execute, () => CanSave);
   }
   protected void Save()
   {
      // [...]
   }

   private RelayCommand? deleteCommand;
   protected IRelayCommand DeleteCommand => deleteCommand;
   protected IRelayCommand GetDeleteCommand(Action execute)
   {
      return deleteCommand ??= new RelayCommand(execute, () => CanDelete);
   }
   protected void Delete()
   {
      // [...]
   }

Derived class:
   //[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSave))]
   public IRelayCommand SaveCommand => base.GetSaveCommand(new Action(Save));
   private void Save()
   {
      // [...]
      base.Save();
   }

   //[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanDelete))]
   public IRelayCommand DeleteCommand => base.GetDeleteCommand(new Action(Delete));
   private void Delete()
   {
      // [...]
      base.Delete();
   }

UPDATE:
I have come up with a better and simpler solution (I think):
Abstract methods defined in the base class and implemented in the derived class. So I can keep all the commands in the base class and call both methods implemented by the derived class.
Base class:
   protected abstract void SaveInDerivedClass();

   [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSave))]
   private void Save()
   {
      // [code that needs to be executed in the BASE class]

      SaveInDerivedClass();
   }


   protected abstract void DeleteInDerivedClass();

   [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanDelete))]
   private void Delete()
   {
      // [code that needs to be executed in the BASE class]

      DeleteInDerivedClass();
   }

Derived class:
   protected override void SaveInDerivedClass()
   {
      // [code that needs to be executed in the DERIVED class]
   }

   protected override void DeleteInDerivedClass()
   {
      // [code that needs to be executed in the DERIVED class]
   }

